# ClientDataSet.DisableControls é seguro?

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Numa rotina simples para alimentar um **ClientDataSet**, primeiro executo o comando `ClientDataSet.DisableControls` (antes do `try`) e ao final do *while* (no `finally`), executo o comando `ClientDataSet.EnableControls`.
Mas o problema é que os controles do **ClientDataSet** não são habilitados com o `EnableControls`.
Percebi que se eu executar mais vezes na sequência o `EnableControls`, aí sim os controles são restaurados.

Pesquisando na web, vi que esse problema não é novo.
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=203983

Enfim, quero saber:
É seguro usar o `DisableControls/EnableControls`?
Há algum detalhe necessário para que esses comandos funcionem, ou é realmente mais um *bug* do Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trabalho com Delphi a 12 anos, migramos o Software da empresa de Delphi 5 para o a mais nova IDE e nunca, digo, nunca tivemos problemas com isto!

A utilidade aqui é que ao desabilitar os controles o usuário não percebe quando percorremos um `DataSet`, sem ele, dou exemplo de um Grid, é perceptível quando posiciona o DataSet em algum registro, ou quando o percorre.

Fonte Documentação interna da IDE XE10.2.2:

`Data.DB.TDataSet.EnableControls` *Re-enables data display in data-aware controls associated with the dataset.*

`Data.DB.TDataSet.DisableControls` *Disables data display in data-aware controls associated with the dataset.*

Ou seja, extremamente inofencivo, pois, trata-se apenas da exibição dos dados.

[EnableControls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.EnableControls)

[DisableControls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.DisableControls)

Comment: Realmente constatei um problema na rotina, o `DisableControls` estava dentro de um `while`, sendo que o `EnableControls` estava fora...  
Corrigi colocando o `DisableControls` antes do `while` (não havia percebido devido a complexidade da rotina e por haver mais de um laço na mesma).